# How do I get the 'random' module to work? Did I forget to import something, or do I need to install anything?

Tags: python, random

My code looks like this:

```
import random
x = random()
print (x)
```

and I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\random.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = random()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What did I do wrong? From my understanding, random should be installed with python, shouldn't it?

Comment: As the traceback says, `random` is a module that contains functions/classes that you may call like `random.randint()` etc.

Comment: It also looks like you have named your own file `random.py`, which may be shadowing the builtin `random` module. Rename your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the module you just import.
For example `random.random()` or `random.randint()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `random.random()` like this.

```
import random
x = random.random()
print (x)
```

or you can import specific functions in `random` module like this.

```
from random import random
x = random()
print (x)
```

Comment: Neither of those did the trick.
With `random.random()` I get a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` and with `from random import random` I get an `ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from partially initialized module 'random'`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using whole `random` module which is why it's throwing the `TypeError` error. instead use random.random() if you want `float` type random numbers or random.randint() for `int` numbers.

```
import random
x = random.random()
print(x)  # returns a random floating number between 0 and 1
```

Note: `randint()` method returns an integer number selected element from the specified range. The method is an alias for `randrange(start, stop+1)`

Comment: That did not work, I get this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from partially initialized module 'random'`

Comment: what is your script name? did you name it `random.py`?

Comment: Yes, then I changed it and got the same error. Now I got it to work, turns out I needed to delete the '_pycache_' folder. Thank you for your help!

Comment: most welcome. if my answer helps you give a upvote. thanks